# Probability of ith card in the ith positon

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose n cards numbered 1, 2, …, n are laid out randomly in a row. Let $A_i$ denote the event that card $i$ appears in the ith position of the row, which is termed as a match. What is the probability of obtaining
at least one match?

I tried to approach this problem in the following way:

Let us say we have n blanks; the first blank has n-1 possibilities to fill it up (Since any number but 1 can occupy that position).
Then the second position has $n-1$ possibilities, and so on. In total, there are $(n-1)!$ ways to fill in the n-blanks. And the total number of ways to fill n blanks without any constraints is $n!$.

Let the probability expression be $P(A)$. To get the desired answer, we subtract $P(A)$ from 1, making thee final value $(1-1/n)$

However, the answer seems to be incorrect. What am I missing here?

Comment: The associated formulas are in https://oeis.org/A000166 .

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in the manner you were attempting.

What you want is $1 -$ P(arrangements where none of the cards are in their "proper" position, that is [deranged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) )

You could attempt it directly using inclusion-exclusion, viz

$\large
\frac{n!-\binom{n}{1}(n-1)!+\binom{n}{2}(n-2)!-\binom{n}{3}(n-3)!+\cdots+(-1)^n\binom{n}{n}(n-n)!}{n!}$

or use one of the "ready made" shortcuts like $!n$ (subfactorial $n$) to get the number of derangements $D_n$, then

$Pr = 1 - \frac{D_n}{n!}$

Comment: What exactly is wrong in my approach? I am not getting it.

Comment: As the simplest example, with $4$ elements, the first slot does have $3$ choices to have a wrong element, but suppose it is filled by #2,the next slot also has $3$ wrong choices (#1,#3,#4) . You need to study **derangements** closely.